# Change Facebook App Name

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm so far unsuccessful in finding a way to change the name of my Facebook App. Originally i was a little bit too specific with my name and want to change it to a more general app name.

I've got the option to change the "Display Name" which seemingly doesn't display anywhere.

The reason for the change is posting Facebook Ads which will display the app name, not display name.

Please advise.

Comment: If your app is in app center, you need to resubmit the app details page for approval after you change the app - before that the old name will be used

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I've added the answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer in the end was as Igy suggested.

Your new display name will only be visible to users after a change when you have your Facebook app reviewed and approved.

Until then they will continue to see the old Display name.